# Is there a default DotsPageIndicator for Android mobile (not wear)?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to use a `ViewPageIndicator` for my `ViewPager`. I've found [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/wearable/view/DotsPageIndicator.html) DotsPageIndicator, but it seems like it's only for `AndroidWear`. Funilly enough, there is pretty much exactly the same thing on the homepage of every Android 6 device, as can be seen in the image below (click for larger image).

[image]

So, is there something I'm just simply missing, and can it be implemented just as easy as all default Android stuff? Or do I still have to use an external library? If the latter is true, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question quite some time ago, but forgot I still had this one open, so I'm going to try to answer it now, with what I remember from back then. So be aware, it might not be perfect, but I'll try to make it as good as possible.

---

You will need the `viewPagerIndicator` library. I believe the way to do this is to open your `build.gradle (Module: app)` Gradle script, then go to `dependencies` and add `compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'`

The result should look something like this:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
}
```

Next, you'll need to add the `PageIndicator` of your liking (I picked the Circle version) to your XML. This should be in the same XML file as the `ViewPager` you want to have these indicators for. My file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <com.example.tim.timapp.CustomStuff.Misc.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"/>

    <!-- Note that I use a custom ViewPager for app-specific reasons. -->
    <!-- It doesn't matter if you use a custom or default VP as far as I know. -->

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circlePageIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:strokeColor="@color/lightGrey"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, you'll need to initialize the `PageIndicator`, and set its `ViewPager`. This is done in the `onCreate....()` method for whatever you're using. As a basic rule: This part should be in the same method that returns your view. Mine for instance is in a `onCreateDialog()` method, because I have a `ViewPager` inside a `Dialog`.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate view
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpager, null);

    // Initialize viewpager and set max amount of off screen pages
    mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    // Initialize pageradapter and set adapter to viewpager
    mPagerAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(inflater);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Initialize circlePageIndicator and set viewpager for it
    CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.circlePageIndicator);
    circlePageIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
}
```

If I recall correctly, that should be all.
For reference, you can check out the website for this `ViewPagerIndicator` here:
http://viewpagerindicator.com

**Please be aware:** As far as I remember, you do **not** have to download anything from this website (at least not if you use `Android Studio`). The first step you did should have taken care of getting the `VPI` ready.

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarification. Again, I can't guarantee this is exactly how it works, but it should get you going.

Answer (score -1):

Place this code is your java class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedBundle);
    addDots();//setup dot layout 
    selectDot(0); //set initial dot position
 }

protected void addDots() {
        dots = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        LinearLayout dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pager_dots);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DOTS; i++) {
            ImageView dot = new ImageView(this);
            dot.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_pager_dot_not_selected));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);
            dotsLayout.addView(dot, params);

            dots.add(dot);
        }
    }

    public void selectDot(int idx) {
        Resources res = getResources();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
            int drawableId = (i == idx) ? (R.drawable.ic_pager_dot_selected)
                    : (R.drawable.ic_pager_dot_not_selected);
            Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(drawableId);
            dots.get(i).setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }
```

Here is the layout.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager_dots"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/activity_wizard_footer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Here is the dot images.
[image: Not selected]
[image: Selected]

Comment: What element should the XML use? Should it be inside the Viewpager or not?

Comment: @Timmiej93 Use outside the Viewpager layout.

Comment: But what element should it be? You close the XML tag, but don't open it.

Comment: Thank you. Do you also have the drawable files for the dots?

Comment: @Timmiej93 drawable also added

Comment: I might be stupid, but how would you use these PNGs? I'm only used to XMLs, and can't get the PNGs working in any way

Comment: The dots you provided are PNG files. When I import these into Android Studio, they go into the folder MipMaps. All images I ever worked with are XML files, which are located in the drawable folder. I normally get these files via R.drawable.filename, but I don't know how to use the files from the mipmap folder.

Comment: @Timmiej93 move files from mipmap to drawable and then use them